# Webix textarea is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, webix

Im new at Webix. I have this form where I insert a textarea.

```html
webix.ui({ rows:[ { view:"form", id:"log_form", elements:[ { view:"textarea" ,height:700}, { margin:5, cols:[ { view:"button", value:"Salva" , type:"form" }, { view:"button", value:"Annulla" } ]} ] } ] });
```

How can I make it responsive because if I set the height of textarea this is not responsive anymore? Is there a way? I want the textarea to be with this height I put there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "autoWidth" attribute with the set value as "true".

```
webix.ui({ rows:[ { view:"form", id:"log_form", elements:[ { view:"textarea" ,height:700, autoWidth:true}, { margin:5, cols:[ { view:"button", value:"Salva" , type:"form" }, { view:"button", value:"Annulla" } ]} ] } ] });
```

Comment: autoWidth makes it responsive but if I remove the height.